# How can hydrogen have negative enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, hydrogen

According to the data found [here](https://h2tools.org/hyarc/hydrogen-data/hydrogen-enthalpy-different-temperatures-and-pressures), the enthalpy of hydrogen at very low temperatures can be negative. I fail to wrap my head around how this can be in line with $H = U + pV$, where $U$, $p$, and $V$ cannot be smaller than zero.

Comment: Please, pay attention that boiling point of hydrogen is about −259.16 °C, and in the table you refer they included two points at -255C  (p=0.1MPa and p=1MPa)  close to liquid state.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that the points are in the intermediate state between liquid and gaseous. However, how a cold enough liquid can have negative enthalpy wasn't clear to me until I read the accepted answer.

Comment: Is it clear for you why condensation going before boiling point so that enthalpy becomes negative? What do you think, how they measure enthalpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a **perfect gas** you would be right, all these quantities are positive.

But even hydrogen is **not** a perfect gas. At very low temperature, interactions between hydrogen molecules start to play a role. Interaction energy is **negative**. For a liquid or a solid this is obvious : to extract a molecule from a liquid or a solid you have to give it energy. But even a gas which is **not** perfect has a negative "binding" energy.

At low enough temperatures, this binding negative energy may well dominate the positive contributions of the kinetic energy (which, **for a perfect gas**, is the only contribution to $U$, which in that "unphysical case" is **always** positive) and the product $pV$.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't even aware that solids and liquids have negative enthalpies at low enough temperatures. Your explanation how we need to give it energy to take matter away helped me to see how this is possible.